# How to persist redux state data in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I've recently set up the redux with my Next.js project, now i'm dealing with persisting redux data, so that on every page refresh, i can have the persist state. So i've added redux-persist for handling this scenario as it's the best solution with react-redux, but I don't know why it's not working here in next.js with next-redux-wrapper or withRedux library too. So kindly help me with this issue, is there anything like redux-persist existed ?(I don't want cookie's solution though), if yes, then kindly suggest me the references with examples, it will be really helpful. Thanks in advance...

I was actually trying to persist the redux state after every page refreshes, so i have used redux-persist with next-redux-wrapper too, but i'm getting errors

/store.js

```
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
    import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
    import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
    import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
    import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

    const persistConfig = {
      timeout: 0,
      key: 'root',
      storage,
    };
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

    export default () => {
      return createStore(persistedReducer,
        composeWithDevTools(
          applyMiddleware(
            thunkMiddleware
          )
        ));
    };
```

/_app.js

```
    import App, { Container } from 'next/app'
    import React from 'react'
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
    import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper';
    import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
    import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
    import store from '../store';

    class MyApp extends App {
      static async getInitialProps ({Component, ctx}) {
        return {
          pageProps: (Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx) : {})
        };
      }

      render () {
        const { Component, pageProps, reduxStore } = this.props;
        const persistor = persistStore(store);
        return (
          <Container>
            <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
              </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
          </Container>
        )
      }
    }
```

I expect it will persist the state, but I'm getting error like this : "redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to memory storage.TypeError: baseReducer is not a function"

Comment: Why don't you follow the recommended example from next.js github. https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux You should export your _app class with `redux-persist`

Comment: I've followed the same example provided by zeit in their docs, but I couldn't get the solution. Btw, I don't know how to export _app class with redux-persist man, can you please help me here, so i can try it out..

Answer (score 12):

Create a your own `storage.js` file.
Put the file in the main project folder.
Use this code...

```
import createWebStorage from "redux-persist/lib/storage/createWebStorage";

const createNoopStorage = () => {
  return {
    getItem(_key) {
      return Promise.resolve(null);
    },
    setItem(_key, value) {
      return Promise.resolve(value);
    },
    removeItem(_key) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    },
  };
};

const storage = typeof window !== "undefined" ? createWebStorage("local") : createNoopStorage();

export default storage;
```

Go to the `store.js` file created in the Nextjs example.  Replace the  `import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'` with `import storage from './storage'` to import the file you created instead.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see your reducer here, but I'm guessing you are not handling rehydrate case.
In order to persist state on page refresh your reducer should handle REHYDRATE case. This is an example from my code:

```
const Account = (state= INIT_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    /// other cases here....
    case REHYDRATE:
        const rehydrated = (action && action.payload && action.payload.Account) || {}
        return { ...state, ...rehydrated }
    default: return { ...state };
```